# Unit Vector Based on Angle with $XY-YZ-XZ$ Planes

Tags: vector-spaces, 3d, coordinate-systems

This may be a simple one but lets assume I have $3$ angles $(a,b,c)$ and I want to know what unit vector makes such angles with the $XY-YZ-XZ$ planes. Another question is that I wanna know if $a$, $b$ and $c$ are independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angles $a$, $b$ and $c$ cannot be independent since the three angles are just determining a point on the surface of the unit sphere.

Comment: Yeah, same as what I expected. Any answers for the first part?

Comment: Do you know a parametrization for the unit sphere?

Comment: Yeah. I have derived some equations myself. Just wanna double check if they are correct. Lets assume I have (a,b,c) as the angles and (X,Y,Z) as the unit vector then: tan(a)=Y/Z, tan(b)=X/Z, tan(c)=X/Y. Does this make any sense? and the fact that X^2+Y^2+Z^2=1.

Comment: You can parmetrize the sphere with cos and sin of two angles

Comment: Ohh yes, I got myself confused with tangent! Thanks! Accepted as the answer.